# Device Reports Loaded Media When No Media Is Present

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, disk, drive

I have 2 USB SD Card readers. One has a card in it, the other does not. The system reports correctly within the Disk Management control panel:

Disk 1 Removable 7.40 GB Read Only

- (G:) 7.4 GB RAW

Disk 2 Removable (E:) No Media

- (No Volume Info)

However, when I use ManagementObjectSearcher to search for the drives and query their properties, I get:

\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1: Media Loaded

\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2: Media Loaded

This is obviously Incorrect, and I'm wondering why. Here's the code I'm using

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType=\"USB\"")) {
                    using (ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get()) {

                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc) {
                            using (mo) {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{mo.Properties["DeviceID"].Value as string}: Media Loaded? {mo.Properties["MediaLoaded"].Value}");
                            }
                            _operationFragment.ProgressValue = (i + 1 / moc.Count);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What happens if you swap the card around? My initial guess is that the device is ready to work once it has a card inserted, so its driver is reporting an existing FAT32 or exFAT filesystem even though it has no media (ie, think of a hard drive with no platters...the drive electronics are still there to report to the system, but it truly has no storage media)

Comment: @Tim I don't think that's it. I took the card reader out and plugged it back in just to make sure it wasn't "remembering". I'll try it again soon, but I'm not optimistic. 
If the file system is relevant, the cards have a custom one, which is why they show up as RAW when they are loaded. At any rate, MediaLoaded seems pretty specific. "If True, the media for a disk drive is loaded, which means that the device has a readable file system and is accessible. For fixed disk drives, this property will always be TRUE." In this case neither would seem to be true.